# sqlalchemy cannot find dialect during runtime - python3

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use sqlalchemy to connect to sql server

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import urllib

conn_string=“Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=x.x.x.x;Database=Test_DB;uid=test;pwd=test”
conn_string=urllib.parse.quote_plus(conn_string)
engine=sa.create_engine(“mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}&autocommit=true”.format(conn_string))
```

This runs fine using python interactive window

However when I wrapped the above code snippets into a file I keep   having the error message: **Can’t load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:mssql.pyodbc**

File structure:
ABC

- test.py

```
import sys
import os
import sqlalchemy as sa
import urllib

sys.path[0] = os.path.dirname(os.getcwd())

def connect_db():

    conn_string=“Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=x.x.x.x;Database=Test_DB;uid=test;pwd=test”
    conn_string=urllib.parse.quote_plus(conn_string)
    engine=sa.create_engine(“mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}&autocommit=true”.format(conn_string)
    Other code to read from db and process data

if __name__ = ‘__main__’:

    connect_db()
```

when i run python test.py the error appears. Does anyone know what is going on?

I expect sqlalchemy should be able to connect to SQL Server like it does when using interactive window

Comment: Why `sys.path[0] = os.path.dirname(os.getcwd())` ? What is that supposed to accomplish?

Comment: That is because i want to import a module from another folder. Trying to debug the code today and found out that when I remove the ```if __name__ = ‘__main__’:``` and just call the function it works fine

Answer (score 0):

If you try to do it as specified in the documentation, does it works? Like creating URL using sqlalchemy instead of parsing one with urllib.

```
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL
connection_string = "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=x.x.x.x;DATABASE=Test_DB;UID=test;PWD=test"
connection_url = URL.create("mssql+pyodbc", query={"odbc_connect": connection_string, "autocommit": True})

engine = create_engine(connection_url)
```

Also, please verify that it is correclty installed on your machine: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Install.

Comment: It still didn’t work and the code snippets work in interactive window it just didn’t work when running from a file